# Spider markers google map native

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I would like to know if there is a solution for ionic 2 like this:

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

This is using the javascript api of google maps. I need a solution with ionic native maps.
Thanks

Comment: solution for what?

Comment: A solution for when you have more than one marker in the same place like this:
jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo-1.html
(click in the markers)

Answer (score 0):

The marker clustering of the cordova-googlemaps-plugin (ionic google maps) has been working currently.
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1006

If you are **really** interested in, please contact to me by e-mail.

If you are **just** interested in, please wait for a while. The feature will be public in a month (and for ionic 2).

Comment: I already did clustering with this tool:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/supercluster

What i need is when you have more than one marker in the same location. See this: https://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo-1.html
(click on the markers)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a spider markers, a CSS change can handle the situation. Like if multiple exist on single point multiple can be shifted up by some px.